# How to solve HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503 JSOUP(I Tried All solutions)

Tags: java, jsoup

During my Big Data project I have to develop a JSOUP script to get Paris 2018 meterological data and store them

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; 
Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 
Safari/537.36";

    int numberDay = 1;
    for(numberDay=1; numberDay<32 ; numberDay++ ) {
        //une condition sur le numberDay =1 puisque dans URL 1  = 1er
        if(numberDay==1){

            String First=numberDay+"er";
            String url = "https://www.infoclimat.fr/observations-meteo/archives/"+First+"/"+listMois.get(1)+"/2018/paris-montsouris/07156.html";
            System.out.println(url);
            //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();

            //appel de la methode DataCollect
            dataCollect.GetData(doc);

        }


    else if(numberDay!=1) {

            String url = "https://www.infoclimat.fr/observations- 
meteo/archives/"+numberDay+"/"+listMois.get(1)+"/2018/paris- 
montsouris/07156.html";
            System.out.println(url);
            Document doc = 
Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();

            dataCollect.GetData(doc);

        }
    else{
            System.out.println("erreur");
        }


}
```

I tried all the solutions of user_Agent but i have the same errors(URL works on the Browser)

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error 
 fetching URL. Status=503
```

the error is displayed in the 8th day so he can detect that it's a robot after 8 requests.

Comment: Does even the browser work if you sit there and reload constantly?

Comment: Yes i reload constantly web page and it works perfectly but with not with the code

Comment: Try to add some delay, to slow down your requests' rate.

Comment: do you have an idea about the parameter I need to add to make a delay between requests? you mean timeout() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by putting a thread to widen the time between queries

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```